# How to create a simple crosstab across multiple fields in R

Tags: r, crosstab

I feel like there's a simple answer to this, since there are so many similar questions on this forum, but none of them seem to apply for some reason.

I have survey data along with segment assignments uploaded via excel into R. The structure of my data is basically this (around 50 fields, including a segment assignment, for each of 330 respondents):

| RespondentID | Household.Size | Children.in.household | Segment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Yes | Segment 1 |
| 2 | 2 | No | Segment 3 |
| 3 | 1 | No | Segment 2 |
| 4 | 2 | No | Segment 5 |
| 5 | 4 | Yes | Segment 1 |

As you see above, some variables are numeric, some are categorical. I want to create a simple crosstab, no stat testing needed, that summarizes each field per segment. Ie. for each segment, what % of respondents in that segment have a household size of 1, 2, 3, etc; what % have children in the household, etc.

I've experimented with both CrossTable and crosstab (I realize the latter is just a wrapper for the former), but I can't get anything to work. Most of the solutions posted in forums are for individual fields, and I'd like to avoid generating individual tables for each of 50 fields, if possible.

Please let me know if there's a straightforward way to approach this!

Comment: Can you describe more what this would look like? These seem to me like they naturally should be separate tables, but maybe I haven't seen the format you're thinking of.

Comment: @JonSpring I'm guessing that the request was for an automated generation of the 50 tables.

Comment: Based on the crosstabs we've gotten from contractors, I believe you're correct - there would be a separate table for each field. However, I would prefer not to generate a separate table for 50 fields - ie. have 50 lines of code each generating a table - if I don't have to (although I'd settle for that if I had to - I don't know how to accomplish that either).

Comment: @IRTFM exactly - I was hoping there was a function that would essentially say "for each of these fields, generate a summary table where the rows are the field values and the columns are the segments, and cells contain the % of each segment that corresponds to each field value"

Comment: look at `tbl_summary` from the `gtsummary` package.

Comment: Thank you George Savva tbl_summary worked for me! I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and assuming we have a small number of segments (viz. 5) and a large number of variables try the table1 or [similar](https://github.com/kaz-yos/tableone#similar-or-complementary-projects) packages.  (Convert all columns to factor first if you want to treat numeric columns as discrete items.)

```
library(table1)

tab1 <- table1(~ . | Segment, DF[-1])
as.data.frame(tab1)
```

giving:

```
                                Segment 1         Segment 2         Segment 3         Segment 5           Overall
1                                   (N=2)             (N=1)             (N=1)             (N=1)             (N=5)
2        Household.Size                                                                                          
3             Mean (SD)      3.50 (0.707)         1.00 (NA)         2.00 (NA)         2.00 (NA)       2.40 (1.14)
4     Median [Min, Max] 3.50 [3.00, 4.00] 1.00 [1.00, 1.00] 2.00 [2.00, 2.00] 2.00 [2.00, 2.00] 2.00 [1.00, 4.00]
5 Children.in.household                                                                                          
6                   Yes          2 (100%)            0 (0%)            0 (0%)            0 (0%)         2 (40.0%)
7                    No            0 (0%)          1 (100%)          1 (100%)          1 (100%)         3 (60.0%)
```

### Note

```
DF <- 
structure(list(RespondentID = 1:5, Household.Size = c(3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 4L), Children.in.household = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
"Yes"), Segment = c("Segment 1", "Segment 3", "Segment 2", "Segment 5", 
"Segment 1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your help! I couldn't get the above solution to work, table1() required too many inputs and I kept hitting errors. However, @George Savva's suggestion of tbl_summary did exactly what I needed it to. I had a little trouble exporting the output, which is a large file that can't be coerced into a data frame, but I managed it by opening the results in a new window and copy-pasting to excel. Thank you!!

Comment: You should try all the packages in the link in the answer and not just the example package. The list in the link includes table1, gtsummary and many other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Another package that might work for this is janitor, then the tabyl function within that package:

https://garthtarr.github.io/meatR/janitor.html#tabyl()